# mysql best way to sum values in multiple column in the last row

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I have a table:

| Product Category | Number Purchased | Total Discount $ | Total Price | Total Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| car 1 | 1 | 100 | 1000 | 900 |
| car 2 | 2 | 200 | 2000 | 1800 |
| car 3 | 9 | 900 | 10000 | 9100 |
| car 4 | null | null | null | null |

```
SELECT
    categ.category_name AS 'Product Category',
    SUM(order.quantity) AS 'Number Purchased',
    SUM(order.discount) AS 'Total Discount $',
    SUM(order.price) AS 'Total Price',
    (SUM(products.price) - SUM(order.discount)) AS 'Total Sales'
FROM
    products
LEFT JOIN
    orders USING (product_id)
LEFT JOIN
    categ USING (category_id)
GROUP BY
    categ.category_id
ORDER BY
    categ.category_name
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to produce the sum of the columns in the last row, demonstrated below:

| Product Category | Number Purchased | Total Discount $ | Total Price | Total Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| car 1 | 1 | 100 | 1000 | 900 |
| car 2 | 2 | 200 | 2000 | 1800 |
| car 3 | 9 | 900 | 10000 | 9100 |
| car 4 | null | null | null | null |
| null | 12 | 1200 | 13000 | 11800 |

so far I've tried:

```
SELECT
    categ.category_name AS 'Product Category',
    SUM(order_items.quantity) AS 'Number Purchased',
    SUM(order_items.discount_amount) AS 'Total Discount $',
    SUM(order_items.item_price) AS 'Total Price',
    (SUM(order_items.item_price) - SUM(order_items.discount_amount)) AS 'Total Sales'
FROM
    products
LEFT JOIN
    orders USING (product_id)
LEFT JOIN
    categ USING (category_id)
GROUP BY
    categ.category_id
 
UNION ALL

SELECT  
    NULL, 
    SUM('Number Purchased'), 
    SUM('Total Discount $'), 
    SUM('Total Price'),
    SUM('Total Sales')
FROM
    products
LEFT JOIN
    orders USING (product_id)
LEFT JOIN
    categ USING (category_id)
ORDER BY
    categ.category_name
```

doesn't seems to be working, any suggestions?

Comment: I think you shouldn\`t use command `group by categ.category_id` at the second part, cuz you are selecting all categories and that is just sum, no need to group by some column

Answer (score 0):

You can do that programatically in your application, that might be the fastest implementation. If you really want to aggregate in MySQL (which executes a second sub-query) and do `UNION ALL`, then just fix the second part.

You don't need to `GROUP BY` there:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (SELECT
    categories.category_name AS 'Product Category',
    SUM(order_items.quantity) AS 'Number Purchased',
    SUM(order_items.discount_amount) AS 'Total Discount $',
    SUM(order_items.item_price) AS 'Total Price',
    (SUM(order_items.item_price) - SUM(order_items.discount_amount)) AS 'Total Sales'
  FROM
    products
  LEFT JOIN
    orders USING (product_id)
  LEFT JOIN
    categories USING (category_id)
  GROUP BY
    categories.category_id
 
  UNION ALL

  SELECT  
    NULL AS 'Product Category',
    SUM(order_items.quantity) AS 'Number Purchased',
    SUM(order_items.discount_amount) AS 'Total Discount $',
    SUM(order_items.item_price) AS 'Total Price',
    (SUM(order_items.item_price) - SUM(order_items.discount_amount)) AS 'Total Sales'
    products
  LEFT JOIN
    orders USING (product_id)
  LEFT JOIN
    categ USING (category_id)
  ) t
ORDER BY 'Product Category'
```

Comment: It worked! But I still have trouble using ORDER BY on top of everything, any suggestions?

Comment: @sleepfreak you want to order by Category Name? I just added that - it should be in the first `SELECT`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, it gives me syntax error,  also tried putting parentheses for both select as well

Comment: I am not sure what the difference between tables `categories` and `categ` is? 
I just edited the answer with ORDER BY outside of the UNION ALL

Comment: my mistake it's the same it just a typo when I post it

Answer (score 0):

Using `UNION` does not enforce the sorting order by the `ORDER BY` clause unfortunately. Try using `with rollup` in the group by clause:

```
select `Product Category`,sum(`Product Category`),sum(`Total Discount $`),sum(`Total Discount $`),sum(`Total Price`) 
from
    (SELECT
        categ.category_name AS 'Product Category',
        SUM(orders.quantity) AS 'Product Category',
        SUM(orders.discount) AS 'Total Discount $',
        SUM(orders.price) AS 'Total Price',
        (SUM(products.price) - SUM(orders.discount)) AS 'Total Sales'
    FROM
        products
    LEFT JOIN
        orders USING (product_id)
    LEFT JOIN
        categ USING (category_id)
    GROUP BY
        categ.category_id) t
GROUP BY
        `Product Category` with rollup
ORDER BY
    `Product Category`
;
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this actually works, it gives me error 1055, should I remove the clause ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ?

Comment: I suppose so. As you your query does have column `categ.category_name` which is not defined in the group by list. Or you can try the any_value function. In this case, try `SELECT
    any_value(categ.category_name) AS 'Product Category',`

Comment: any_value doesn't work and it also put car4 in the null spot under 'product category'

Comment: Your original query returns a derived table. We can work on that derived table.  I've made some adjustment. Would you please try that for me?

Comment: By the way , the table name `orders` in the Left Join clause does not match the ones `order` in the select list, so I took the liberty of changing them to `orders`.